# Hall's Lie groups book, chapter 4, exercise 14

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am currently studying on my own B. Hall's Lie groups, Lie algebras and representations book and solving its exercises. I got stuck at exercise 14 from chapter 4,

> Exercise 14. Let $(\Pi,V)$ be a finite-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ with associated representation $π$ of $\operatorname{su}(2)$, which extends by complex linearity to $\operatorname{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$. If $X, Y$ and $H$ are the usual basis elements for $\operatorname{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$,
> $$
>   H = \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 0\\
>     0 & -1
>   \end{bmatrix},\quad
>   X = \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & 1\\
>     0 & 0
>   \end{bmatrix},\quad
>   Y = \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & 0\\
>     1 & 0
>   \end{bmatrix}
> ~,$$
> compute $T=e^Xe^{-Y}e^X$ and show that
> $$\tag{1}\label{ec:id} THT^{-1}=-H.$$
> Use this result to give a different proof of Point 3 of Theorem 4.34.

The referred result is the following:

> **Theorem 4.34.** *If $(π,V)$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{sl}(2;\mathbb{C})$, not necessarily irreducible, the following results hold*
>
> (...)
>
> 3. *If we define
>    $$ S=e^{π(X)}e^{-π(Y)}e^{π(X)},$$
>    then $S$ satisfies
>    $$Sπ(H)S^{-1}=-π(H).$$*

I'll explain in the following what I have done.

Firstly I computed
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    -1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
and after checking that \eqref{ec:id} holds I observed that $T\in\operatorname{SU}(2)$ and that $iH\in\operatorname{su}(2)$. Thus, by theorem 3.20 of Hall's book, $T(iH)T^{-1}\in\operatorname{su}(2)$ and
$$
-π(H)=π(THT^{-1})=-iπ(T(iH)T^{-1})=-iΠ(T)π(iH)Π(T^{-1})=Π(T)π(H)Π(T)^{-1},
$$
where we have used that if $\Phi:G\to H$ is a Lie group homomorphism between matrix Lie groups $G, H$ and $\phi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$ is the induced Lie algebra homomorphism then $\phi\left(A X A^{-1}\right)=\Phi(A) \phi(X) \Phi(A)^{-1},$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{g}, A \in G$
(theorem 3.28 of same book).

From here, I don't now how to continue. I would like to carry on perhaps doing something like $Π(T)=Π(e^Xe^{-Y}e^X)=Π(e^X)Π(e^{-Y})Π(e^X)$ but we aren't allowed to do so since $Π$ is only defined on $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ and $e^X, e^{-Y}\notin\operatorname{SU}(2)$.

Any help will be appreciated :)